# What is the difference among these: (I was wondering vs I wondered vs I had wondered)

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, past-continuous

What is the difference among these sentences:

> Well, there are a lot of questions that I missed on the test, but I
>   can’t figure out why I got them wrong. I **was wondering** if you could
>   explain them to me.
>
> Well, there are a lot of questions that I missed on the test, but I
>   can’t figure out why I got them wrong. I **wondered** if you could
>   explain them to me.
>
> Well, there are a lot of questions that I missed on the test, but I
>   can’t figure out why I got them wrong. I **had wondered** if you could
>   explain them to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if you could explain them to me.

This has the meaning of:

> I hope you can explain them to me. / I would like it that you
>   explained them to me. / I was thinking you could explain them to me.

So, "I was wondering" is a continuous action in regard to the event. In this particular case, however, "I was wondering" is considered a polite request to explain them, instead of a past continuous action.

> I wondered if you could explain them to me.

"I wondered" is past tense. Past tense is in regard to an action that was in the past and is over at the present moment:

> A moment ago I wondered if you could explain them to me. / I wondered yesterday if you would visit me today.

And:

> I had wondered if you could explain them to me.

"I had wondered" is in regard to a point of time way back in the past and is used when describing that action in comparison to the present or another point of time.

> E.g. I had wondered if you could have explained them to me back then, but now
>   I know you couldn't have explained them to me as they were too
>   complicated for you too. / I had wondered about it back then, but it's
>   no surprise to me now.